# Determine current USB address of device in Windows

Tags: windows-10, usb, wireshark

**TL;DR:** How did my Win10 system arrive at a USB source address of `2.5.5` for my mouse (in Wireshark) when USBPcapCMD lists it as hub 2, port 6?

- Can I determine the `2.5.5` address without guessing?

**Details:**

I am trying to match the USB source address from a USBPcap in Wireshark to the "port" listed in the USBPcapCMD.exe mapping.

Here is the "source" address for my mouse in Wireshark:

[image: Wireshark_USBPcap_Device_Address]

Here is the "port" for my device as shown by USBPcapCMD:

[image: USBPcapCMD output]

So how did we get to `2.5.5` when USBPcapCMD lists the device more arbitrarily?

- Is there a utility that will help me figure out the actual USB source address without deriving it from behavior observed in Wireshark?

**Some additional notes:**

- I know that USB addresses are prone to change
- I know that my mouse is `2.5.5` in this instance because when I wiggle it around the capture fills up with interrupts until I stop.

Answer (score 1):

The address x.x.x is comprised of the following three parts:

1. USB Controller / Hub Path #
2. The USB Connection Device Address
3. The device USB Endpoint ID

The path # (1.x.x) can be found by running USBPcapCMD, finding the device I want to capture in WireShark, and noting which USBPcap number the device is listed under.

The Device Address (x.1.x) and Endpoint ID (x.x.1) can be found running USB Device Tree Viewer, selecting the device, and then looking at the device Connection Information.

Comment: Hey thanks for the info! Is there a way that one could write a script to arrive at the same address that the OS uses without using USBPcapCMD and WireShark first? Not sure that there's an answer out there!